# Can I tell if my VPS server (win 2008) is hosted on Hyper-V from within the image?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

Is it possible, from within a windows 2008 virtual private server, to tell if the image is hosted in Hyper-V or some other virtualization technology? For example, are there any guest-os extensions that might be installed?

Background: I previously bought a VPS server from a company who offer VPS images hosted on either Virtuozzo or Hyper-V. I thought my original server was on Hyper-V, but it turned out I bought the wrong package. Now that the month is over I've ordered another server, and want to check I haven't made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows 2008 running on Hyper-V the network adapters usually show up as "Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter" in the Device Manager.

Also, [here's some info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tonyso/archive/2009/08/20/hyper-v-how-to-detect-if-you-are-inside-a-vm.aspx) on accessing the BIOS information via WMI/VBS to determine if you're inside a VM or not.

Hope that helps...